# How does sar collect/calculate disk utilization %?

Tags: linux, performance, sar

I'm pretty sure `sar`'s disk utilization % shows how much of the disk is being utilized at any given time, but how does it calculate that?  I found:

> %util
>
> Percentage of CPU time during which I/O requests were issued to the device (bandwidth utilization for the device). Device saturation occurs when this value is close to 100%.

In the sar man page, but that doesn't answer much for me - the CPU could be issuing I/O requests infinitely but that doesn't necessarily mean that the disk is at capacity - would it not be more appropriate to measure when requests start becoming latent as a ceiling for how hard a disk is being hit?

Answer (score 1):

sar (a.k.a. sysstat) includes [iostat](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/iostat.c), which reads `/proc/diskstats` and `/proc/partitions`

iostat's [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iostat.1.html) defines `%util` as:

> Percentage of elapsed time during which I/O requests were issued to the device (bandwidth utilization for the device).

---

### Information Sources

1. [sysstat's iostat source](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/iostat.c)
2. [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iostat.1.html)

---

### Further Reading

1. [The Linux kernel user’s and administrator’s guide » CPU load](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cpu-load.html)
2. [The Linux kernel user’s and administrator’s guide » I/O statistics fields](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/iostats.html)
3. https://brooker.co.za/blog/2014/07/04/iostat-pct.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which kernel version are you using /proc/partitions or /sys/block/hda/stat or /proc/diskstats, but you answer your question thes file have all the required field to calculate CPU utilisation with sar.

Hope it will help you.